# PHP Search has an error possibly on trim

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to use $PHP_SELF to collect the value from a form and return the results on the same page.  The page itself is a PHP page, if that matters.

I can't seem to see the error I clearly have.  The error handler I'm using tells me that the error is on line 22 (the line with $searchTerm = trim($name);) but I'm suspicious that it could be further down the php commands, though I've tried all kinds of combinations of commenting out things and stripping things out and reducing things, etc, and I've never gotten the page, on initial load, to not give me the error on line 22, which is the start of the query section of the page.  If I put the form ahead of all of the php from the query, I can see the form, but I still have the error. If I put the form below the query, I can't see the form.

The weird part is that the form works perfectly.  And, after hitting the submit button, I don't have the error displaying, just the results, which are correct. I suppose it's possible that the error is in how I'm enclosing (or not) the query handling portion of it, but at this point, I can't see it. I've put this together from several questions on this site and tutorials I've found through Googling. So I feel comfortable that the commands are correct, I just can't see why I show an error.

Here's the latest version of the code, which does exactly the same error as the rest of the attempts I've made at it. Should the entire section of PHP, from the $searchterm to the mysqli close be enclosed in brackets or something?  I'm using a call to a conn file above the initial if statement.  And this is a combination of two pages that function exactly correctly - I'd used search.php, the name of the other page, in the form action. Somehow, combining them is making things go terribly, terribly wrong.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo "User has entered this name : <b> $name </b>"; 
}

//capture search term and remove spaces at both ends, if there are any
$searchTerm = trim($name);

//connect to database
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

//MYSQL search statement
$query = "SELECT CompanyName FROM Companies WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%$searchTerm%'";

$results = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

//Check whether there were matching records in the table by counting the number of results returned
if(mysqli_num_rows($results) >= 1) 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        echo '<div class="query">' . $row['CompanyName'] . '</div>';
    } else
        echo "No match found for " . $searchTerm;

 mysqli_close($dbc); 
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Learn to use prepared statements

Comment: **Advice:** Escape your input string before using it in a query with [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or your script will be SQLi exploitable!

Comment: `$results = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die($mysqli->error); //see if any wrong with query`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is most likely caused because you are closing your `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` too early. `$name` is only being set on the form post `$name = $_POST['name'];`, so on initial page load, it is not set when you call `$searchTerm = trim($name);`. Try moving the closing bracket `}` from `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` to after `mysqli_close($dbc);` so all your php code is not run until after the form is posted.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo "User has entered this name : <b> $name </b>"; 
// remove closing bracket from here

//capture search term and remove spaces at both ends, if there are any
$searchTerm = trim($name);

//connect to database
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

//MYSQL search statement
$searchTerm = mysqli_real_escape_string($searchTerm); // Escape user data to prevent SQL Injection
$query = "SELECT CompanyName FROM Companies WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%$searchTerm%'";

$results = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

//Check whether there were matching records in the table by counting the number of results returned
if(mysqli_num_rows($results) >= 1) 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        echo '<div class="query">' . $row['CompanyName'] . '</div>';
    } else
        echo "No match found for " . $searchTerm;

 mysqli_close($dbc); 
}  // move closing bracket to here
?>
```